# How to remove trailing zeros using ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a column `DECIMAL(18,4)`.  when I insert data like *123.45* it becomes *123.4500*
I want to show it in `SSRS` like  123.45.
How to remove those zeros in `SSRS`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I try and find solution:

I use Expression for value:

```
 =IIf(IsNothing(Fields!FieldName.Value), "", IIf(IsNothing(Fields!FieldName.Value), "-", CInt(Fields!FieldName.Value * 10000) / 10000))
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what exporting formats your need you can set the number formatting to `0.####;(0.####)`

I know this is compatible with the SSRS viewer and exporting to PDF, but Excel would take `123.0000` and show it as `123.` instead of just `123`

Answer (score 2):

You can change the data type returned to SSRS to a FLOAT. That should do it :-)

Comment: Yes, I have found that it's easier to change the data-type returned from the query with at `CAST(x AS FLOAT)` than to try to monkey with it later in SSRS.

Answer (score 1):

I dont agree with the accepted answer, casting to a string is another workaround:

```
=Str(NumericValueWithVariableDecimalPlaces)
```

Unfortunately a consequence is no numeric formatting settings will apply and setting cell Alignments *to right* causes numbers to be misaligned.

Answer (score 0):

Open **SSRS Query Designer** and add:

`SELECT CONVERT(DOUBLE PERCISION,FIELD) FROM TABLE SOURCE`

[image]

OR add to your select result from your Store Procedure source

```
SELECT CONVERT(DOUBLE PERCISION,FIELD) FROM TABLE SOURCE
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove trailing zeros: CDbl(Fields!YOURFIELD.Value)

Answer (score -1):

This can be done in the SQL which you can do by casting the value to DECIMAL(18,2)

```
ex:
  CAST(FieldName as DECIMAL(18,2))
```

but if you really want to do it in SSRS. You can right click on the textbox that the field is displaying in and go to textbox properties. In the pop-up box choose 'Number' and set the Category to 'Number' and then decimal places to 2. This should correctly display the value.

You could also right click on the textbox and go to expression and say this in the expression popup box:

```
   =FormatNumber(Fields!FieldName.Value,2)
```

Comment: that's wrong if i have 124.4560 returns 124.45 instead of 124.456

Comment: You didn't say mention that it could be 124.4560. You're question makes it seem like it will always be four decimal places (124.4500) with two extra zeroes at end. In regards to you're question above yes my answer is correct. You should edit you're question to say that it should remove trailing zeroes when the value is 123.4000 or 123.4500 or 124.4560 as that's is what it seems like you're really looking for not just when its 124.4500.